# Strange SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx behavior

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, dllimport

If i create a C# console application which sets the console Buffer/Window Width and Height (using Console.*-Methods) to 80x25 (or any other specific size) the console-window has no scrollbars.

When i use GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx to read the consolebuffer-settings it reports a window.Right and window.Bottom of 79x24. If i write the read CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX back the window will get scrollbars.

**Question: Are there any C#/.NET-framework methods interfering or is this standard behavior?**

I've seen examplecode for C on the internet which is always doing window.Right++ and window.Bottom++.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Comment: So you can answer one of the questions?

Comment: If you would ask just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, I think you're getting scroll bars because your window is actually getting smaller. It's a bug.

See [35901572](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901572/setconsolescreenbufferinfoex-bug) and note, for reference that the [examples on PInvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx)
always fix the size.

Try adding a couple lines after you call GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx:

```
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(handle, ref currentScreen);
++currentScreen.srWindowBottom;
++currentScreen.srWindowRight;
```